# Stopping an failed spool from creating file?

Tags: bash, sh, sqlplus

My script is spooling a SELECT query and generating a report to another location. I'm inducing errors to see how my script reacts. Is there a way to simply not generate a file in the event there is a failure to spool data from the database such as if the script runs but the database is down? As it stands, it looks like it's simply spooling the SP2 errors to the file which will go to the target folder which is what I don't want to happen. In some cases, the entire SELECT statement will spool into the file. Are there any tips or recommendations on how to prevent this? I'm a newbie at all of this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1) separate output from errors; 2) save output to a temporary location; 3) write code to process errors; 4) only move output to permanent location if no errors

Comment: Hi jhnc,

This is what I'm cooking up in my mind. I'm going to generate the file in temp directory. Use grep to find the usual suspects (grep -q -eERROR -e^TNS -e^SP2 -e^ORA). I currently have a function that will run sqlplus and spool the results to the appropriate directory. I'll rewrite this to spool to a temp directory where a separate function will grep to find errors. If errors are found, rm, else mv to the appropriate directory. Thank you for your input!

Comment: What is "SP2"? Please include your current code in the question and include what you want to happen which is not happening.